# jQuery all but not descendent of specific type

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have following markup,

```
<div custom="">
  <div>
     <template>
        <a custom="">  (anything inside template should not be selected)
        </a>
     </template> 
  </div>
</div>

<a custom=""></a>
```

I want to select all element that has custom attribute but not anything that is inside "template" node.

I have tried following but does not work,

```
$(":not(template *) [custom]")
$(":not(template) [custom]")
$(":not(template) *[custom]")
$(":not(template *)[custom]")
$(":not(template)").filter('[custom]')) // this does not work either...
$(":not(template,template *)").filter('[custom]')) // this does not work either...
```

But this does not work. Any simpler way to do this? I am not getting any elements in query.

I know, template is not a standard html. But its my custom tag to have proper tag within html instead of wrapping in non standard script where markup validation is not possible.

Comment: btw, shouldn't you use instead the data attribute like: `data-custom=""` ?

Comment: Well, there are many libraries that use data- attributes, and it takes too many characters to type in, if I am to prefix data-custom- to all my attributes, it will be very long and also it might conflict with some, so we have decided to use custom (there is a proper word in place of custom that part of our naming convention). Infact there are many custom- attributes till two levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a shot.

```
$('[custom]:not(template *)');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mjmwx/).

This selects all elements with a `custom` attribute (including descendants of `template`), and then throws away the elements which are a descendant of a `template` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try matching the `[custom]` attribute first then with `:not` selector.

```
$("[custom] :not(template)")
```